# pandas series with different time indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code

```
 ser = pandas.Series(range(5),index=pandas.date_range('20130722','20130726',freq='D'))
ser1 = pandas.Series( range(4,9), index = ser.index + datetime.timedelta(days=3))
```

And when I plot them one after the other (`ser.plot()`, then `ser1.plot()`), I get the correct picture.

Now change the definition of ser1 as follows

```
ser1 = pandas.Series( range(4,9), index = ser.index + datetime.timedelta(days=3.1))
```

and repeat the two plot commands (in the same order as above).  The picture I get shows only ser1 and the x-axis says "27 Jul 3982".  If you first do `ser1.plot()` and then `ser.plot()`, you also get an incorrect picture but slightly different that the first incorrect one.  (I would post pics, but don't have enough reputation points...)

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

I've imported `matplotlib.pyplot` as `plt`.

This gets them on the same figure, which I think is what you wanted.  I've essentially resampled `ser1` to the lower frequency timestamps of `ser`.  You could do this explicitly with `In [33]: ser1.resample('D', how='mean')`, but in this case it doesn't matter since there's just one observation at each day.  The important thing is that they share the same x-axis units if you're trying to put them on the same plot.

```
In [25]: fig = plt.figure()

In [26]: ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

In [27]: ax.plot(ser.index.date, ser)
Out[27]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x10616e150>]

In [28]: ax.plot(ser1.index.date, ser1)
Out[28]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x107981050>]

In [29]: plt.draw()
```

[image]

If you want to avoid matplotlit altogether, join the two series first and call plot on the resulting DatFrame:

```
In [37]: pd.concat([ser, ser1.resample('D', how='mean')], axis=1).plot()
Out[37]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x1064aa190>
```

This handles the tick labels better by default:

[image]

Comment: Agreed.  Your code works.  So if do ax.plot(ser1.index,ser1) (which is using pylab's plot command), this is fine.  But when you call pandas' plot command, i.e. ser1.plot(ax=ax) after ser.plot(ax=ax) then it doesn't plot correctly.  This will work fine if ser1 is defined with an integer days increment, but not with a float increment.

Comment: Just make sure that the two indices are at the same frequency and it should be fine. `ser.plot()` followed by `ser1.resample('D', how='mean').plot()` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you not able to hold your plot. When you are plotting the next plot.. you may be overwriting the previous plot.

Try the following...

```
figure()
ser = pandas.Series(range(5),index=pandas.date_range('20130722','20130726',freq='D'))
ser.plot()
figure()
ser1 = pandas.Series( range(4,9), index = ser.index + datetime.timedelta(days=3))

ser1.plot()
figure()
ser1 = pandas.Series( range(4,9), index = ser.index + datetime.timedelta(days=3.1))
ser1.plot()
```

Comment: This code generates 3 separate figures.  This works ok.  The problem is why ser1 won't plot on same axis as ser, when the timedelta days parameter is a non-integer.